# create dynamic dashboard of singlestat panel based on template variable

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating, prometheus-node-exporter

I would like to create a dynamic dashboard of my cluster nodes. this dashboard will be composed of multiple single state panels. each one shows the status and name of a node

So this what I have done:

- create a template variable list_of_vm = label_values(up{job="node_exporter"},instance) by checking multi-value combo
  the result of this is something like ip1:port, ip2:port, ... , ip7:port
- create un single state panel with repeat panel set to list_of_vm. And in metrics I set up{instance="$list_of_vm",job="node_exporter"}

After checking all instances in the template variable, the panels are correctly duplicated, but their value is wrong because in metric the query is evaluated as : up{instance="$list_of_vm",job="node_exporter"}
when list_of_vm = "ip1:port+ip2:port+..+ip7:port"

And I am expecting to have ip1:port for the first panel, ip2:port for the second one...

Do you have any idea to fix this problem